Problem deploying a Java Web Project MVC in TomCat server in VSC
I have a Java project, in Maven, java 17, Im trying to deploy the .war file using Tomcat Server 9 with Community Server Connetors Extension of VSCode.
First way, a have a Servlet.java class configured, when I deployed in the server works fine and shows the .jsp.
Second way, a have a web.xml and a spring_mvc_servlet.xml for configuration, and a Controlador.java class, but this second way run the server showing 404 error.
---Web.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">

    <!-- Configuracion del dispatcher servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring_mvc_servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Ubicacion URL del servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

---spring_mvc_servlet.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Habilitar soporte para anotaciones en los controladores -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="es.pildoras.spring.mvc"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    
    <!-- Configuración de los resolutores de vistas -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/vistas/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>

---Controlador.java class:
package es.pildoras.spring.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class Controlador {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String redirigir(){
        return "index";
    }
}

Also in TomCat log I recived the error:
WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.setVersion Unknown version string [5.0]. Default version will be used.

I think everything is configured correctly.
I tried run the proyect originally in VScode, then in Net Beans, the same problem; and Eclipse, the same problem.
There is the repository for test:
https://github.com/AlonzoAlex/Spring-MVC-1
Thanks
